# MySQL Create Trigger if no exists?

Tags: mysql, triggers, database-migration, mybatis

```
SELECT trigger_schema, trigger_name from information_schema.triggers;

+------------------------+------------------+
| trigger_schema         | trigger_name     |
+------------------------+------------------+
| tv_client1             | public_id        |
+------------------------+------------------+
```

I want to added an existing Trigger `public_id` for the tv_client2.
How to create Trigger if it not exists?

The final result should be:

```
SELECT trigger_schema, trigger_name from information_schema.triggers;

+------------------------+------------------+
| trigger_schema         | trigger_name     |
+------------------------+------------------+
| tv_client1             | public_id        |
+------------------------+------------------+
| tv_client2             | public_id        |
+------------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query `SELECT trigger_schema, trigger_name from information_schema.triggers;` shows you the database name and the trigger name. In your case `public_id` trigger has been created in `tv_client1` database. If you want the same trigger to be exist in `tv_client2` database then you can execute the same `CREATE TRIGGER public_id ...` code against `tv_client2` database as well and the same will then be reflected in `information_schema.triggers`.

Answer (score 1):

use a union statement

```
SELECT trigger_schema, trigger_name from information_schema.triggers
union all
select "tv_client2" as trigger_schema, "public_id" as trigger_name
from information_schema.triggers;
```

your question is a little hard to understand so I believe this is what you're asking. If you already have an existing public_id then the code should be

```
SELECT trigger_schema, trigger_name from information_schema.triggers
union all
select "tv_client2" as trigger_schema, trigger_name
from information_schema.triggers;
```